# VB Script Dynamic Userform

Tags: vbscript

Is it possible to create a dynamic user form using VB Script? The form needs to pull in values from a tool and also from an excel sheet and should also contain checkboxes and textboxes and OK Buttons. (This script is written inside a tool).

If someone could guide me I would really appreciate it. I'm new to VB Script and only know how to create msg boxes and text boxes. Please help!

Comment: Check out [HTA](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742317.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can start from this nice example in HTA : **[HTA input examples](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/tm.aspx?m=35657)**